# How to stop a node cron job

Tags: node.js, node-cron

I want to stop a node cron job on certain conditions.

This is how I started the task to run every 1 second.

```
const runScheduler = (url)=>{
    cron.schedule('*/1 * * * * *', () => {
        console.log('running a task every one second');
        async.waterfall([ getUrlDelay(url), dbMethods.updateUrlResponses(url) ],function(err, success){
            if(err) return console.log('Url Not Found');
        })
      });
}
```

I want to stop this job but unable to do it.

Answer (score 18):

**The below answer may not be relevant now because of the changes done to these packages. The `scheduleJob` was meant to be a pseudocode to just create a job. The objective was to show how to stop them.**

---

Here's a comprehensive summary for instantiating, starting and stopping sheduled cron-jobs for three cron-modules ([cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron), [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) & [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)):

**1. CRON**

In order to `cancel` the job you can create a job with unique name.

```
var cron = require('cron').CronJob;

var j = cron.scheduleJob(unique_name, '*/1 * * * * *',()=>{
    //Do some work
});
// for some condition in some code
let my_job = cron.scheduledJobs[unique_name];
my_job.stop();
```

It should cancel the job.

**2. NODE-CRON**

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

const url_taskMap = {};
const task = cron.schedule('*/1 * * * * *',()=>{
    //Foo the bar..
});
url_taskMap[url] = task;
// for some condition in some code
let my_job = url_taskMap[url];
my_job.stop();
```

**3. NODE-SCHEDULE**

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

let uniqueJobName = specificURL;
// Shedule job according to timed according to cron expression
var job = schedule.scheduleJob(uniqueJobName,'*/10 * * * * *', function(){
     //Bar the foo..
});
// Inspect the job object (i.E.: job.name etc.)
console.log(`************** JOB: ******************`);
console.log(job);

// To cancel the job on a certain condition (uniqueJobName must be known) 
if (<someCondition>) {
    let current_job = schedule.scheduledJobs[uniqueJobName];
    current_job.cancel();
}
```

Summarized by [Aritra Chakraborty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1203844/aritra-chakraborty) & [ILuvLogix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9793532/iluvlogix)

Comment: For node-cron the solution from @amoghesturi works. Also it has a `cron.getTasks()` method and each task has a `.start` and `.stop` method.

Comment: I currently ran into a similar issue with job-instantiation (IOT publishing via mqtt) and termination. Thanks for the info - maybe we could expand your answer to cover cron, node-cron & node shedule - would be a nice reference for the future - what do you think?

Comment: You are most welcome to edit the answer. I will be sure to approve it. :-)

Comment: ok, give me an hour or so and I'll write a comprehensive summary ;)

Comment: np - reputation are just points to me anyway - I put our credits on the bottom ;) Please check the summary for any errors or typos and edit if you find any ;)

Comment: some of the method signatures do not seem to be correct. require('cron').CronJob does not have the method "scheduleJob" and nor does require('node-cron')

Comment: Yes, the schedulejobs were basically pseudocodes. The main point was to show how to stop them, but now the syntaxes and constructors are different as heck. so it is not relevant that much.

Comment: How to stop a job if node server restarts and the schedule is saved in db, but the job instances list is gone after server restart?

Answer (score 1):

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

  var task = cron.schedule('* * * * *', () =>  {
    console.log('will execute every minute until stopped');
});
task.stop();
```

Comment: Actually there are many jobs which are running in my program . This function (runScheduler) is being called for different urls. I just want to stop the job for a particular url.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used [cron-job-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-job-manager) to create, read, update, delete jobs.

After you add a job `manager.add('key','* 30 * * * *', taskFunction)`
you can easily stop it `manager.stop('key')` or delete it `manager.deleteJob('key')`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same Issue. Using `node-schedule` solved the issue with a custom `ID` per Job:

start the custom Job:

```
  const campaignId = "MY_CUSTOM_ID"
  let job = schedule.scheduleJob(campaignId, '* * * * * *', function () {
    console.log('running campaign: ' + campaignId)
  })
```

stop the custom Job:

```
  const campaignId = "MY_CUSTOM_ID"
  let current_job = schedule.scheduledJobs[campaignId]
  current_job.cancel()
```